# Q.all promise never runs then callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am bit lost as to how `Q.all` works. 
I have the following code snippet ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL6hdvx4/)):

```
function callUrl(remoteEndPoint){
  return $.ajax({
    url: remoteEndPoint,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
      console.dir(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("error");
    }
  });
}
Q.all([callUrl("https://httpbin.org/get"), callUrl("https://httpbin.org/undefined")]).then(function(){
    console.log("Done");
});
```

The first call to `callUrl` will succeed, the second will fail (will return an error as the url does not exist). 
I am expecting the `Q.all` to execute the `then` callback like what `ajax.always` does but this isn't the case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain a `catch` method and callback for that, because `Q.all` will return a rejected promise when it encounters a rejected promise.

You get called back concerning a rejected promise via `catch` (or the optional second callback you can pass to `then`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So then gets called only when all the promises succeed?

Comment: Indeed, it is like you say. If any reject, the first rejection reason is passed to the `catch` handler instead. Potential other pending promises are no longer monitored by `Q.all` when that happens.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation (you have my +1 :) ) I will accept Kurt G answer as he is spot as well and answered first - I hope you won't mind.

Comment: No problem. On my page, I see my answer is one minute older than his, but no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The 404 is an error that has propogated from the server, into your JS application.

use `.catch`

```
Q.all([callUrl("https://httpbin.org/get"), callUrl("https://httpbin.org/undefined")]).then(function(){
    console.log("Done");
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log("err",e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So then gets called only when all the promises succeed?

Comment: @GETah , yes, all promises need to succeed for then to resolve. That is why your call back was not being called.